# Progressbar progress Calculation

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I'm writing a Swing app where there is a `JProgressBar`. The case is, I've a folder with some n files (n can be 1 or up to 400). I want to update my progress bar as the program runs, I'm unable to know how can I calculate and update the progress bar. Right now below is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    int rowNumber = writeData(files[i], sheet, rowCount, workbook);
    rowCount = rowNumber;

    int percent = Math.round(((float) (i + 1) / files.length) * 100f);
    setStatusText(percent);
}
```

I want to know a way where I can calculate and update my progress bar as I progress. Though I have 2 files or 200 files the progress bar should update accordingly.

For example If I've 2 files in my directory, for every file that I process, the progress bar should update by 50%, and if there are 200 files, for every 2 files, the progress bar should update with 1%. Since I'm not sure of how many files I have in directory, I'm very much confused.

Comment: Unclear. What's "_a better way_" ? What is the problem you have with that code? Please edit question to clarify.

Comment: Hi @kebs, Thanks for that quick question(suggestion for me) updated my question. Please let me know if anymore clarification is needed. :)

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: *"Since I'm not sure of how many files I have in directory"* What do you mean, you don't know? `files.length` (already mentioned in the code) is the exact number. What results do you get from `System.out.println(percent);` from within the loop?

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson, I'm using SwingWorker, There is no issue with the `freezing`, I just need a calculation. To be simple I've pasted only a block of code where I'm stuck.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).